# What age did Dick Grayson lose his virginity to Liu?

Tags: dc, batman, nightwing

In [Nightwing Vol 2 #134](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Nightwing_Vol_2_134), when Dick Grayson meets Liu and starts sleeping with her, was it before he turned 17 or after? In the beginning of the issue Dick Grayson tells Batman his 17th birthday would be a month after but after that he left and starts working with these people. How much time passes before he got seduced and betrayed by Liu? Was he 16 or 17 already?